# query where timestamp < timestamp not working?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, where-clause

2016-08-18 04:52:14 is the timestamp that I'm getting from the database to keep track from where I want to load more records which are less than that

this is the code

```
 foreach($explode as $stat){
            if($statement == ""){
                $statement .= "`userid` = '$stat'";
            }else{
                $statement .= "OR `userid` = '$stat'";
            }
        }
}
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `things` WHERE $statement AND `times` < '$time' ORDER BY `times` DESC LIMIT 20");
```

`times` is the timestamp field I'm trying to query against but it is returning dates greater than that

example

```
id--------------times
63              8/18/2016 1:25:43 AM
---
---
---
---
---
93              8/18/2016 6:41:12 AM
```

so the $time variable is 2016-08-18 04:52:14 but it is returning rows 93 down limit 20, I could really use some advice thank you for your time

Comment: what is the datetype of column times?

Comment: @Jens it is timestamp

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Format of the date in your query

Comment: Are you sure that times column is timestamp? It seems a simple textual column, which would explain the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: can you update the example with actual output from `select id, times...`?

Comment: it is timestamp I have the default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it puts it in automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be because of the conditions in your query where you are using `OR` and `AND`.

```
SELECT * FROM `things`
WHERE ($statement)
  AND `times` < '$time'
ORDER BY `times` DESC
LIMIT 20"
```

By putting brackets around your `$statement` you might avoid the `OR` being attached to the time comparison.

---

**Explanation**

I am fairly certain what is happening, if you debug the actual query which is built by your PHP, is that it looks something like this:

```
WHERE `user_id` = 1 OR `user_id` = 2 AND `times` < '2016-08-18 04:52:14'
```

So the second `user_id` in this example is considered part of the `times` condition like this:

```
WHERE
  (`user_id` = 1)
     OR 
  (`user_id` = 2 AND `times` < '2016-08-18 04:52:14')
```

What you actually want is:

```
WHERE
  (`user_id` = 1 OR `user_id` = 2)
     AND
  (`times` < '2016-08-18 04:52:14')
```

---

**Additional Improvement**

You could probably use the SQL `IN` operator as an alternative anyway, which makes your code a bit more elegant and easier to read.

So if your user IDs are in a comma-delimited string or something already, don't bother exploding them (as I am assuming you have done from your code). Just pass them in to the query:

```
$userIds = "1, 2, 3, 4";

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `things`
        WHERE `user_id` IN($userIds)
          AND `times` < '$time'
        ORDER BY `times` DESC
        LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: that worked, thanks you saved me an hour of frustration haha

Comment: Without knowing what all is in $statement I'm going to go with this. Chances are the boolean logic isn't working like the op thinks it should and this will either solve it, or bring about resolution if it screws things up more. Good catch.

Comment: excellent thanks again, I can accept in a minute, ive been stressing out about this for about an hour trying all different kinds of things, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try converting your $time to unixtimestamp and query like:

```
WHERE $statement AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`times`) < '$time' ORDER BY `times`
```